# Haskell weird expression

Tags: haskell

I would like to understand why the following is a valid expression in Haskell:

```
Prelude> let e = (+) (-)
Prelude> :type e
e :: (Num (a -> a -> a), Num a) => (a -> a -> a) -> a -> a -> a
```

More strange is that any expression in the form

```
e 1 2 3 4 ... N
```

whatever N are all valid expressions of uncomprehensible type. For example,

```
Prelude> :t e 1 2 3 4 5
e 1 2 3 4 5
  :: (Num ((a -> a1 -> t) -> (a -> a1 -> t) -> a -> a1 -> t),
      Num (a -> a1 -> t), Num a1, Num a) =>
     t
```

Is this an unfortunate consequence of currying and type inference?

Clarifications are welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange Haskell expression with type Num (\[Char\] -> t) => t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31503707/strange-haskell-expression-with-type-num-char-t-t)

Comment: @jberryman The logic behind the type derivations is similar, but both questions are very good and different examples of Haskell's expressive power. Their answers are very informative and deserve to be independent questions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not an "unfortunate consequence". In fact, some might see it as a feature! The types of `(+)` and `(-)` are

```
> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
> :t (-)
(-) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

It's important to realize that this is valid for *any* type `a`, even if `a` is a function type. So, for example, if the type `b -> b -> b` has a `Num` instance, then you could restrict `(+)` to

```
(+) :: Num (b -> b -> b) => (b -> b -> b) -> (b -> b -> b) -> b -> b -> b
```

by simply setting `a = b -> b -> b`. Because of currying, the parentheses around the last three `b`s are unnecessary (you could write them in but they would be redundant).

Now, `Num b => b -> b -> b` is exactly the type of `(-)` (with the proviso that `b` itself has to have a `Num` instance), so the function `(-)` fills the first "slot" of `(+)` and the type of `(+) (-)` is

```
(+) (-) :: (Num b, Num (b -> b -> b)) -> (b -> b -> b) -> b -> b -> b
```

which is what you observed.

---

This raises the question of why on earth it might be useful to have a `Num` instance for functions at all. In fact, does it even make sense to define a `Num` instance for functions?

I claim that it does! You can define

```
instance Num a => Num (r -> a) where
    (f + g) r = f r + g r
    (f - g) r = f r - g r
    (f * g) r = f r * g r
    abs f r = abs (f r)
    signum f r  = signum (f r) 
    fromInteger n r = fromInteger n
```

which makes perfect sense as a `Num` instance. And in fact, this is precisely the instance you need to interpret your expression `e` -

```
> let e = (+) (-)
> e 3 2 1
4
```

Buh?!?

What happened is the following. Since `(Num a) => r -> a` is a valid `Num` instance for any `r`, you can replace `r` with `a -> a`, which shows that `(Num a) => a -> a -> a` is also a valid `Num` instance. So you have

```
-- Remember that (+) f = \g r -> f r + g r

  (+) (-) 3 2 1
= (\g r s -> (-) r s + g r s) 3 2 1 -- definition of (+) on functions
= (\  r s -> (-) r s + 3 r s) 2 1   -- beta reduction
= (\    s -> (-) 2 s + 3 2 s) 1     -- beta reduction
=            (-) 2 1 + 3 2 1        -- beta reduction
=            (2 - 1) + 3            -- since (3 2) = 3 and (3 1) = 3
=               1    + 3
=               4
```

A little convoluted (in particular, make sure you understand why `3 2 = 3`) but not too confusing once you've expanded all the definitions out!

---

You asked for the derivation of the type of `(+) (-)` that Haskell uses. It relies on the idea of "unification" of type variables. It goes something like this -

1. You know that `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` and `(-) :: Num b => b -> b -> b` (I use different letters because we will want to mash these together).
2. If you are going to put `(-)` into the first slot of `(+)` you must have `a ~ b -> b -> b`, so the combined type is
3. `(+) (-) :: (Num a, Num b, a ~ b -> b -> b) => (b -> b -> b) -> (b -> b -> b)`
4. Now you "unify" `a` with `b -> b -> b` (as indicated on the left of the fat arrow, by the `~` sign) which leaves you with
5. `(+) (-) :: (Num (b -> b -> b), Num b) => (b -> b -> b) -> (b -> b -> b)`
6. If we remove the right-most parentheses (because they are redundant) and rename `b` to `a`, this is the type signature that Haskell infers.

Comment: I am beginning to understand all this Haskell power, but I expect that all this power is not used in real-world code, if anything else, because I do not see how this could be useful in practice. Does anyone know of useful examples of this?

Comment: Another question. Can you change your answer to provide a type derivation for (+) (-) in a mathematical way, that is, in a way that Haskell uses itself?

Comment: In answer to your first question - yes! For example, the paper [Beautiful Differentiation](http://conal.net/papers/beautiful-differentiation/) by Conal Elliott presents an Automatic Differentiation algorithm that takes advantage of the `Num` instance for functions, and is particularly clear and simple to read (hence "beautiful" differentiation). Since automatic differentiation is used in optimization, machine learning, aeronautics and finance, I claim that this is an example of something both "useful" and "real-world".

Comment: In answer to your second question, I just provided the derivation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There's so much stuff here to grok. I did not know the syntax you are using in `(f + g) r = ...` ?! I have only seen so far (I am a newbie) functions defined as `f a b c = ...` and `f . g = ...`. So, in Haskell we can have any kind of expression on the LHS of an equation? Is there an accessible place to learn the full Haskell syntax? I have read "Learn you a Haskell ... " and I am reading "Real World Haskell" and never saw this syntax. Clarify please.

Comment: @mljrg No, you can't have just any kind of expression on the LHS, that would add a lot of complexity. This is just a shorthand for writing `f + g = \r -> ...` or `(+) f g r = ...`.

Comment: @DavidYoung So the syntax `(f ...) ... = ...` is just syntactic sugar that allows to express functions with a more mathematical notation.

Comment: @mljrg Yes. You presumably already know that writing the expression `a + b` is just syntactic sugar for `(+) a b`. The same is true when defining a function, so `(f + g) r = ...` is syntactic sugar for `((+) f g) r = ...` which is equivalent to `(+) f g r = ...`. It's just a slightly nicer way of defining the function `(+)`. I could also have written `f + g = \r -> ...` and it would mean the same thing.