# Is there any difference between 2x and 2*x?

Tags: haskell

```
Prelude> :t fmap (\x  -> 2x) []
fmap (\x  -> 2x) [] :: Num (t -> b) => [b]

Prelude> :t fmap (\x -> 2 * x) []
fmap (\x -> 2 * x) [] :: Num b => [b]

Prelude> :t 1 1
1 1 :: (Num (t -> t1), Num t) => t1

Prelude> :t 1 * 1
1 * 1 :: Num a => a
```

Is there any difference between `2x` and `2*x`?

What is the meaning of `Num (t -> t1) => t1`?

Comment: A question about a similar situation: [*Strange Haskell expression with type Num \(\[Char\] -> t\) => t*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31503707/2751851)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any defference between 2x and 2*x?

Yes.  `2 * x` is the number `2` multiplied by the variable `x`.   `2 x` is the result of applying the function produced by interpreting the literal value `2` (`fromInteger 2`) to the variable `x`.

How can `2` be a function?  Well, if you have an instance `Num (t -> t1)` then you can interprete `2 :: t -> t1` and it is certainly a function.  While this is possible, no commonly used library has such a Num instance.  Basically any time you see such a type signature pop up it is due to a syntactic mistake.

EDIT:

Just as a boring example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts  #-}

instance (Num a) => Num (a -> a) where
  fromInteger n = \x -> ((fromInteger n) * x)
```

And its use:

```
*Main> (\x -> (2 :: Int -> Int) x) 5
10
```

There are better examples out there.   IIRC, Lennart has one here on S.O. that provides machinery for expressions such as `2 seconds * 5 hours`.